# ng-include Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I have a main index.html file and in that file, I want to include another .html using ng-include. This is my code:

(I will only upload the relevant code sections, if the whole code is needed, I can edit it)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<!-- include CAPH 3.0.1 default package -->
<link href="lib/caph/3.0.1/caph.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/stylesheet">
<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/stylesheet">
<!-- include jQuery file (you can use AngularJS & jQuery in your environment) -->
<script src="lib/caph/3.0.1/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="lib/caph/3.0.1/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- include the CAPH Package for AngularJS -->
<script src="lib/caph/3.0.1/caph-angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['caph.focus', 'caph.ui']);
myApp.factory('sharedProperties', function(){
  var DEPTH={
    MAIN_MENU: 1,
    RESTAURANT: 2,
    MOVIES: 3,
    MOVIE_SELECT: 4
  };
  var currentDepth;
  var focus = function($event) {
    $($event.currentTarget).css({
      border: '10px solid red'
   });
  }

  var blur = function($event){
    $($event.currentTarget).css({
      border : '3px solid transparent'
   });
  }

  var select = function($event){
    if($event.target.id === "roomservice"){
      currentDepth = DEPTH.RESTAURANT;
    } else if($event.target.id === "vod"){
      currentDepth = DEPTH.MOVIES;
    } else if($event.target.id === "back"){
      currentDepth = DEPTH.MAIN_MENU;
    } else if($event.target.id === "fantasy"){
      currentDepth = DEPTH.MOVIE_SELECT;
    }
    return currentDepth;
  }

  return{
    focus: focus,
    blur: blur,
    select: select,
    currentDepth: currentDepth,
    depth: DEPTH
  }
});

    myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, sharedProperties) {
    $scope.currentDepth = sharedProperties.depth.MAIN_MENU;
    $scope.focus = function($event){
      sharedProperties.focus($event);
    }
    $scope.blur = function($event){
      sharedProperties.blur($event);
    }
    $scope.select = function($event){
      $scope.currentDepth = sharedProperties.select($event);
      console.log($scope.currentDepth);
    }
    $scope.items = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      $scope.items.push({
        text: i+1,
        image: 'image/moviepics/' + (i%2 + 1) + '.jpg'
      });
    }
</script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-if="currentDepth === 4">
      <h1>Pick a movie</h1>
      <div ng-include="'new.html'">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is new.html:

```
<style>
  .list{
    position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
    height: 135px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
 }

  .item{
    background: green;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 3px solid white;
    width: 200px;
    height: 135px;
 }
</style>
<caph-list container-class="list" on-focus-item-view="onFocusItemView($context)"  items="item in items">
   <div class="item" focusable data-focusable-initial-focus="{{$index===0?true:false}}">
     <div class="test" style="width:100%; height:100%; background-size:100% 100%; background: url({{item.image || ''}})"><a href="#"></a></div>
  </div>
</caph-list>
```

I am getting an ng-areq error with a WARNING of angular loaded more than once. For the full error, [please see the attached picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgyiL.jpg)
I hope my question and code is clear
Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you include a template, HTML of relevant section of the page needs to be present in it. 
In your `new.html`, you've included everything from the HTML tag which is unnecessary. Remove those and have only the necessary `div` and other elements.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. I changed new.html to fit what you said. Is this the way you meant? Please note that I deleted the controller in new.html since only one controller is needed and I added $scope.items and the for loop inside index.html @Venkat

Comment: Yes this is how it should look. After you still getting the error?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Can you provide an plunkr where this error is replicating?

Comment: yes I will provide a plunkr/github repository. Just give me a bit to make one. Sorry, for the delay

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Had to read up a bit about Github. https://github.com/sahirug/hotelappdemo

Comment: In your controller.js, you're redefining the app using `angular.module("myapp", [])`. You need to remove that and call `angular.module("myapp").controller()`.

Comment: Please notice that in my index.html I have not included scripts/controllers/controller.js as a script. I did it before, but then I later removed the reference and decided to have my app.js and controller.js in the index.html. Sorry for confusing you

Comment: I think I should actually make it clear because when you run index.html, you do not get any error on the console. So when you run index.html, please select "Select a movie from our extensive movie library" then click on "Fantasy" that is where I get the error

Comment: The error I get when I follow these steps is this: `Error: The caph-list's container and template view should have their own size such as width and height.`. This is coming from the caph library that you are using and not from angular. You need to check caph documentation to resolve this.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot for your help. I was getting the AREQ error as well, but that was due to some problem with the controller which has since been fixed. The caph library error was due to me using ng-if. When I changed the ng-if to ng-show, that error dissipates. Thanks a lot for your help :)